# Do I have to work a certain amount of hours in order to get paid monthly?

Tags: salary, payment, consulting

I work as an office assistant and my pay has recently been changed to monthly. I only work 2 days a week now at 8 hours a day and I don't feel that is an adequate amount to receive just once a month. Are there labor laws on having to work a certain amount of hours to get paid monthly?

Comment: Are there labor laws.... **where**?

Comment: "Are there labor laws on having to work a certain amount of hours to get paid monthly?" Not in the US.

Answer (score 2):

Frequency of paychecks is up to the company. Many pay monthly. Some pay twice a month, or every other week. I haven't heard of any paying more frequently unless they were tiny "mom and pop" businesses or grunt-labor/fast-food minimum-wage jobs.

Cutting the checks more often *is* more expensive for the company. And frequency of pay is  one of the things you agreed to in the paperwork you signed when you were hired.

Comment: A number of states mandate being paid more frequently than once a month. Illinois, Massachusetts, New York for example. See http://employment.findlaw.com/wages-and-benefits/payday-laws-overview.html

Comment: Personally, I work for a company as a developer and they pay every week. It's a large business spanning most of the central US, so they do exist. I would say every other week though is more common.

Comment: @Xrylite: Thanks for the data point; I sit corrected. (I'm on twice a month, which for me works a lot better than "every other week" since bills are due monthly.) Actually I do seem to remember getting weekly checks early in my career, when we still had to fill out timecards in detail... and they were still printed on 80-column Hollerith cards. Stone age technology.